# I want to write "Labb ́e" with special and said: package inputence Error: Unicode character

Tags: text, specials

I want to write an author name in a template provided by conference, but have this error. 
What usepackage should I include?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the author is “Labbé”, input it like that, not with a combining character (that, by the way should go after the accentee, but `pdflatex` can't do it). Otherwise input `Labb\'e` (with a standard quote after the backslash).

Comment: how about `Ḧoldric`?

Comment: Is “H with dieresis” used in some language?

Comment: @egreg, not sure what is dieresis, but is an author name, I put in the conference overleaf template, not working

Comment: Normally `\"H`; in a `.bib` file use `{\"H}`.

Comment: @egreg, thanks. It works

Comment: Double-check the spelling of the name: `Höldric` is what I would expect. `Ḧoldric` in Google gives only 1 result: this page.